# Forgiveness and payments

Tags: united-states, student-loan, payment

I've read in several places around the Student Loans repayment policies and I see a lot of forgiveness perks for having made more than 125, or 300 payments.  I am currently on the IBR repayment plan and I receive a monthly bill for $0.00.  Does this $0.00 count as a payment?

What about the payments greater than the amount due? If I made 300 payments of $1.00 each, would that constitute forgiveness?

Comment: My guess is that the fine print specifies 300 months of on-time payments rather than 300 payments. Can you access the fine print for any of these policies?

Comment: Yes, I've just recently read some more about it.  Apparently, in order for them to be considered qualified payments, they must be equal to or exceed the monthly amount due, and on time.  If I were to make 10 payments in one month, it would only count as one apparently.

Comment: Judging from that explanation, I suppose that if, for 300 months in a row, I had an amount due of $0.00, and I were under the IBR plan, I would be forgiven.   Oh yeah, the fine print also stated that I must be a full-time employee, making the 300 $0.00 payments impossible, unless I requested a demotion in my hourly wage.

Comment: I'd say you have the makings for a self-answer right there :)

Comment: keep in mind that payments are applied to interest balance first and then to principle. Therefore when it says $0.00 it just means they don't have interest balance that needs paying, says nothing about the principle. In fact, whenever possible, make sure you tell them you want it to go towards your principle and NOT the interest. Otherwise you will be perpetually paying for interest. Although the extra over the interest amount will go towards principle but that's a very small amount after interest is deducted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from that explanation, I suppose that if, for 300 months in a row, I had an amount due of $0.00, and I were under the IBR plan, I would be forgiven. Oh yeah, the fine print also stated that I must be a full-time employee, making the 300 $0.00 payments impossible, unless I requested a demotion in my hourly wage